# How to run ASP.Net MVC 4 application on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-10

I upgraded my machine to windows 10 release 2.0 from Windows 7 and installed Visual Studio 2017 which I earlier used was VS 2012. My application is not working after setting up IIS 10.
Getting this below error:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Is there something extra that needs to be configured for IIS 10?

Comment: Can you run your code properly in vs 2017 using built in IIS express? Have you properly published app in IIS?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my code is not running in IIS express 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

From the asker in an edit to his question:

> Running Visual Studio in admin mode solved the problem.